# Vertical line showing current week in timeline

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Ok so I recently added a vertical line showing the current week in a chart using this method: http://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/how_to_add_a_vertical_line_to_the_chart.html

but now I want to add one to a sheet without a chart. Is this possible?

So my timeline looks like this: [image: Timeline image]
Is vba needed or is this possible with formulas I really have no idea.

Comment: You could possibly do it with conditional formatting adding borders to cells.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought aswell but it has to auto update every week

Comment: As someone who prefers VBA I would use the `Workbook_Open` event to calculate the column and set the cell borders or draw/move a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it auto update every week using `NOW()` formula:

[image: Marking the week column with conditional formatting]

What you have to make sure is that each column is formatted based on the cell in row `A` (or any other row/column) so you format all cells based on the dates in the first row. To look from each cell to the second row you use `OFFSET($A$1,1,COLUMN()-1)` and get the relevant date for this column. This could be done for any other cell that holds the relevant date for the column, but there must be one like this. The condition in the figure is one for all the table.

**EDIT**:
To match the format of `YYMM` for the date, use the formula (assuming `$D$2` is the upper left cell of the table):

```
=OFFSET($D$1,1,COLUMN()-COLUMN($D$1))=RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2)*100+WEEKNUM(NOW())
```

for the current week, or replace the `NOW()` in it with a cell with the date of interest.

Hope it solves your problem ;)

Comment: Instead of using TRUNC(NOW()), can I use =a cell which holds the current week? My format for date is pretty weird so I have a cell that has a formula to get current week in my desired format.

Comment: Yes. All you need to check is that the cell with the week number and the cell with current week are using the same way to represent the week number, either just a number, of a Excel serial number for dates. If it is always the current week that you want to color, than you can just change it to `=WEEKNUM(NOW(),2)` were `2` is for week starts in Monday, for Sunday replace in with `1`.

Comment: Ok so I put this conditional formatting in D2:IN100
=OFFSET($D$2;1;COLUMN()-1)=$BD$410
$BD$410 is where my current week is 
I have the calendar dates in row 2 in this format: YYWW for example 1630 for year 2016 week 30 1846 year 2018 week 46. So my formula for getting that is a 4x4 cell range with first cell =YEAR(NOW()) 2nd cell =1*RIGHT(BC408;2) taking the last 2 digits of the year and then same for week =WEEKNUM(NOW()) and a cell that combines both of them and multiplies with 1 to get numeric value.

Comment: @FelixTorssell if your date are like `YYWW` change the RHS of the condition to `=RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2)*100+WEEKNUM(NOW())` for the current week in the same format. I have edited the answer to match this format

Comment: ok so now that the 1 in the offset is changed to a 0 the formula kinda works, well it does the formatting but on the wrong week. it highlights week 1626

Comment: Either something wrong with the `OFFSET` (more likely) or with the formula for getting the current date. Try just copy `=RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2)*100+WEEKNUM(NOW())` into a cell and see what it returns, if it's 1629, then it's fine, and you should have another look at your `OFFSET`

Comment: Yeah the RHS is correct. Has to be the offset or something.

Comment: I see it now, you should use `=OFFSET($D$2;0;COLUMN()-1)` because you already start from `$D$2`

Comment: Look carefully `=OFFSET($D$2;` **0** `;COLUMN()-1)` you put `1` instead of `0` for the row offset

Comment: Ok so it seems like whatever I put on RHS it formats 1626 ive even put ´=OFFSET($D$2;0;COLUMN()-1)=1629´ and it still formats 1626. If I change the -1 to 0 it formats 1625 and if I change -1 to -3 it formats 1629. Idk if that is how it is supposed to be

Comment: You right, the correct offset for `$D$2` is `=OFFSET($D$2,0,COLUMN()-4)` because you start at the 4th column, though I don't know why you see a correct value with `-3`

Comment: For more general case use `=OFFSET($D$2,0,COLUMN()-COLUMN($D$2))` where `$D$2` is the upper left cell in the table